# Mobile Web Application Screen Orientation Design

Tags: web-applications, mobile

I'm designing a user interface web page that will be viewed on a mobile device through the device's browser.  Is it common to design two interfaces, one for portrait and one for landscape?  The portrait view looks fine but when I flip to landscape things are of course stretched.  Any ideas on best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common practice to design two interfaces for different window orientations.
Check the window orientation.

```
    //Listen for resize changes
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        // Get screen size (inner/outerWidth, inner/outerHeight)

    }, false);
```

Every time it changes, apply different CSS classes for portrait and landscape modes to the elements on your web page.